# Are github runners safe for actions in private repos

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops

I'm not that familiar with Github Actions and how their runners work but my Devops team are adamant that we cannot run any github actions that require runners because the runners are public and it puts our code at risk of being accessed by 3rd parties.

I know there is an option to use hosted runners, but we're not there yet.

Looking for any advice/references that devs with experience can provide me to dispel these rumours

Answer (score 2):

As per the articles [Link1](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#differences-between-github-hosted-and-self-hosted-runners) and [Link2](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/security-hardening-for-github-actions#hardening-for-self-hosted-runners), GitHub public hosted machines are more secured than self-hosting machines. (At least the articles claim so)

In my experience, big organizations that are very particular about security always go for self-hosting machines which require separate teams to maintain.

The choice should be completely based on what type of application you use and how well you are managing the secure details within the repo.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways for GitHub-hosted Actions runners to connect to resources on your private network, as described in this [2022 June GitHub blog post](https://github.blog/2022-06-01-connecting-to-a-private-network-from-github-hosted-actions-runners/):

1. Use the GitHub Actions OpenID Connect (OIDC) token to authenticate through an API gateway (we [open sourced a reference implementation](https://github.com/github/actions-oidc-gateway-example) as an example, but do note that it requires customization for your use case and is not ready-to-run as-is).
   You would run the API gateway on your infrastructure, but as it is stateless, it can scale quite well for high-bandwidth use cases.
   :
   [image]
2. You can use [WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com/) to create a temporary overlay network between the GitHub Actions runner and your private network.
3. You can use a commercial solution for an overlay network, like [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com/).
   Based on WireGuard, it has similar advantages and disadvantages, except that as a commercial product, it’s even easier to set up and includes NAT traversal.
   Please note that it might require a paid plan for higher data volumes.